# Function inside event listener

Tags: javascript, oop

If a function inside an event listener is called, say for instance, window.load, are all other functions inside said function expected to be ran on load as well? I have an issue with a function being called on window load and that function calling another function. At the last step I want to add an event listener to watch for form submission. However the listener function has no access to the the variables called from the original load listener function.

```
var Handler = {
    
    ajaxURL: null,

    domIDs : null,
    
    httpRequest : null,
    
    init: function(config) {
        this.httpRequest = {};
        this.initConfig(config);
        this.setLoadHandler();
    },
    
    initialize: function() {
    this.initializeDocumentNodes();

    },
    
    setLoadHandler: function(){
        var self = this;
        this.addEvent(window,'load', function() {
            self.initialize();
        });
    },
    
    initializeDocumentNodes: function() {
        this.dom = {};
        for(var key in this.domIDs) {
            this.dom[key] = document.getElementById(this.domIDs[key]);
        }
        
        this.dom['loginForm'].addEventListener("submit", function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            console.log(this.dom['userNameLoginInput']);
            console.log(this.dom['passwordLoginInput']);
            
        });
        
    },
```

`this.dom` is undefined inside the form submit listener.

```
  this.dom['loginForm'].addEventListener("submit", function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            console.log(this.dom['userNameLoginInput']);
            console.log(this.dom['passwordLoginInput']);

        });
```

Could someone please help me to understand this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Create the callback function elsewhere and bind `this` to it before passing it to the addEventListener.

Comment: The variables do exist since I tested it outside of the submit event listener

Comment: I don't think you understand how `this` works in JS. `this` changes depending on _how_ the function is called.

Comment: Do it the same way you did it in `setLoadHandler` -- declare the `self` variable and then use `self.dom`

Comment: Or use arrow functions, which essentially replace the `var self = this;` hack

Comment: Okay thanks for the information. Yeah I am a little bit unfamiliar with `this` in JS.

Comment: @JustinHarris that's fair enough. We all start not knowing. I recommend reading https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes

Comment: I fixed it by assigning this to var self outside the listener according to your suggestions and this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback I will check out the link aswell. Thanks very much <3